# Как вставить DIV рядом с input

Tags: html

Есть код:

```
<td width='8%;'><center><input type='text' value='1'/><div id='pic_1'><img width=20 height=20 src='images/check1.png'/></img></div></td>
```

При выполнении данного кода получается отображение поля input и ВНИЗУ картинка. Как её установить рядом? Оборачивать в div ее обязательно, т.к. исначально картинки там нет, а появляется рядом она при нажатии ENTER по полю input.

Comment: Можно еще заменить div на span

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так! Вот [демо](https://jsfiddle.net/jknkrtsr/)

```
<table>
   <tr><th><center><input type='text' value='1'/></th><th><div id='pic_1'><img width=20 height=20 src='images/check1.png'/></img></div></th></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Почти. Показываю полную таблицу https://jsfiddle.net/jknkrtsr/1/

Comment: Тебе вот так? https://jsfiddle.net/jknkrtsr/2/

Comment: Да, именно так и нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` - блочный элемент, поэтому всегда переносится на новую строку и занимает всю доступную ширину.

Вам необходимо либо добавить к диву стиль `display: inline-block`, либо добавить к обоим диву и инпуту `float: left`, либо заключить все в таблицу (в левом td инпут, в правом див).

Вообще варианты могут быть разные.

Еще в вашем коротком примере большое количество огрехов:
 1. Не закрыт тег `<center>`, кстати, вообще откажитесь от его использования в пользу стилей.
 2. Атрибуты `width, height` задавайте опять же через стили.
 3. Заключайте параметры атрибутов в двойные кавычки.
 4. `<img>` не требует закрывающего тега, то есть пишется так же, как `<input>`, в вашем случае.

Советую вам пройти какой-нибудь курс html, css.